# Finding the total number of k-tuples in a tree

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, graph-theory, depth-first-search

Problem statement : Finding k-tuples in a tree(not mentioned as a binary tree)

You have a Tree with N nodes rooted at 1 where ith node is associated with a value Ai. Now consider the following definition:
**K-Tuple**: A tuple of K+1 nodes (X1,X2,X3,…,XK+1) is a K-Tuple if:
1.) Xi is an ancestor of Xi+1∀1≤i≤K
2.) AXi>AXi+1∀1≤i≤K

Calculate the number of K-Tuples in the tree.

Input :
**line 1**: 2 integers N and K, the number of nodes in the tree and the value for the Tuple type you need to calculate answer for.
**line 2**: N space separated integers where the 
ith integer denotes the value Ai.
**N−1 lines** : X and Y denoting that there is an edge between them.

Constraints:
1≤N, Ai≤100000, 1≤X,Y≤N, 1≤K≤20

Output: The number of tuples

Here is the code I tried

```
public class Solutions {

    static class Node {
        int index, value, tupleLength;
        Node parent;
        boolean inTuple, hasChildren;
        static int tupleCount = 0;

        Node (int index, int value) {
            this.index = index;
            this.value = value;
            this.tupleLength = 0;
            this.parent = null;
            this.inTuple = false;
            this.hasChildren = false;
        }

        // to add an edge between child and parent
        void addChild (Node child) {
            this.hasChildren = true;
            child.parent = this;
        }

        void setTupleLengths (int k) {
            // stop looking for tuple if root node is encountered
            if (this.parent == null)
                return;
            // conditions for a parent node to be in a tuple
            if ((this.parent.index < this.index) && (this.parent.value > this.value)) {
                // if parent is already part of a k-tuple, no need to proceed further, just increment the tuple count and return
                if ((this.parent.tupleLength >= this.tupleLength + 1) && (this.parent.tupleLength >= k)) {
                    tupleCount++;
                    return;
                }
                // if parent satisfies the tuple conditions, then add it to the m-1 tuple to get m-tuple
                this.parent.tupleLength = this.tupleLength + 1;
                // wrote this condition as any (k+1)-tuple will have 2 k-tuples etc.
                if (this.parent.tupleLength >= k)
                    tupleCount++;
                this.parent.inTuple = true;
                this.parent.setTupleLengths(k);
            }
            else {
                // if parent is not in tuple, then start looking for a new tuple which covers this parent's ancestors starting from it.
                if (!this.parent.inTuple)
                    this.parent.setTupleLengths(k);
            }
        }
    }

    // to get all leaf nodes
    static ArrayList<Node> getLeaves (ArrayList<Node> nodes) {
        ArrayList<Node> leaves = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Node node : nodes) {
            if (!node.hasChildren)
                leaves.add(node);
        }

        return leaves;
    }

    // prints the max length of a tuple starting from each node for all nodes
    static void printTupleLengths (ArrayList<Node> nodes) {
        for (Node node : nodes)
            System.out.print ("(" + node.index + "," + node.value + "," + node.tupleLength + ") ");
        System.out.println ();
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        String fileName = "/home/user/Downloads/750ac6c427-input-750a1f8.txt.clean.txt";
        File file = new File(fileName);

        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner (file);

            //int t = sc.nextInt();
            int n = sc.nextInt(), k = sc.nextInt();

            ArrayList<Node> nodes= new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
                int value = sc.nextInt();
                Node node = new Node(i+1, value);
                nodes.add(node);
            }

            for (int i = 1; i<n; i++) {
                int x = sc.nextInt(), y = sc.nextInt();
                nodes.get(x-1).addChild(nodes.get(y-1));
            }

            //printTupleLengths(nodes);

            ArrayList<Node> leaves = getLeaves(nodes);
            for (Node leaf : leaves) {
                leaf.setTupleLengths(k);
            }
            //printTupleLengths(nodes);
            System.out.println (Node.tupleCount);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println (e);
        }
    }
}
```

The input file has test case data - something like this :
7 2
7 6 5 4 3 2 1
1 2
1 3
2 4
2 5
3 6
3 7

output : 4
Explanation :
There are 4 2-Tuples: (1,2,4), (1,2,5), (1,3,6), (1,3,7).

My code gives the right answer for the above mentioned test case, but fails for all others. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong or if I'm missing some cases?

Also I'm not clear on the the time complexity of this solution, is it O(n) as I'm just checking all nodes may be not more than once? So is there a better(right) way to do this?

Comment: The way I understand the problem description, the elements in the tuple do not have to be directly connected in the tree. So `X_i` has to be an ancestor of `X_(i+1)`, but not necessarily a direct ancestor. The way I understand your code, you are only checking for tuples where the elements are directly connected. Your code produces the correct answer on the example, since the example does not contain a disconnected tuple.